# Laravel / Vue3 / Ziggy using current named route

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs, ziggy

So I am using Laravel with Vue3 and Inertiajs. I have included Ziggy to be able to use named routes. This works. But I am trying to add `active` to my link classes whenever the current route is active, like so:

```
<Link :href="route('user.dashboard')"
    class="nav-link"
    :class="{'active': route().current() == route('user.dashboard')}">
     Dashboard
</Link>
```

This doesn't work. What does work, however, is both of the following:

```
:class="{'active': route().current('user.dashboard')}"
:class="route().current('user.dashboard') ? 'active' : ''"
```

But when clicking on another link, the `active` class is not being removed, thus resulting in my "Dashboard" link staying active indefinitely. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this `<Link :href="route('user.dashboard')" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active': $page.props.ziggy.location == route('user.dashboard') }">Dashboard</Link>`

Comment: Giving me an error unfortunately: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.$page.props.ziggy is undefined

Comment: this is so weird considering this is working for me just fine, can you do this `<template>
{{ console.log($page) }}
</template>`  and see if $page is defined or not?

Comment: I figured it out, I tested all the code I posted above in my `menu` component and in my `layout` component and the reactivity was working fine in the `layout` component but not in my `menu` component. I think I need to restructure some stuff.. So for now I am using it like this and it works: `:class="{ 'active': $page.component === 'User/Dashboard' }"`